# Should JUnit3 TestSuite really be used like this?

Tags: java, junit, junit3

I couldn't recall how to use JUnit3 `TestSuite` and after some Googling found this

```
public class MyTestsuite extends TestSuite {
    public static Test suite() {
        final TestSuite s = new TestSuite();
        s.addTestSuite(Test1.class);
        s.addTestSuite(Test2.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but looks very strange to me:

- Why should I create a new instance when being in a suitable class?
- How is anybody supposed to find this out? In the [javadoc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestSuite.html) there's nothing like "write a *static* method called *suite*".
- Why not something as simple as this:

```
public class MyTestsuite extends AbstractTestSuite {
    @Override
    public void suite() {
        add(Test1.class);
        add(Test2.class);
    }
}
```

*Basically, I'm curious if doing it like in my first example is really the way to go. Moreover, I wonder what design decisions might be behind such an interface.*

---

This works too and is maybe a bit less strange:

```
public class MyTestsuite extends TestSuite {
    MyTestsuite() {
        super(Test1.class, Test2.class);
    }
    public static Test suite() {
        return new TestSuite();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example is used if you want to compose test suites and refer to them by class.

Your second example doesn't follow the JUnit 3 patterns for defining suites, as discussed in the [JUnit 3 cookbook](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) discusses the usage of the `static suite` method, used by `TestRunner`.

The `TestRunner` class also [discusses its use in its Javadocs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/textui/TestRunner.html):

> If this class [a `Test` class] defines a static `suite` method it will be invoked and the returned test is run.

Comment: My second example was meant "how it IMHO should look like", not like it is (the extended class is a non-existent `AbstractTestSuite`).

Comment: @maaartinus Oh. Well, that's not how it is. Are you asking why the original designers did it one way and not another? You'd likely need to ask them that.

Comment: I really doubt they know it, it looks like something I could "invent" when you wake me up after a heavy party.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example is better to return the suite subclass `MyTestsuite`, not a `junit.framework.TestSuite`, in this way when one clicks on the suite in the IDE sees that class and not the code of `junit.framework.TestSuite`

```
public class MyTestsuite extends TestSuite {
    public static Test suite() {
        final MyTestsuite s = new MyTestsuite();
        s.addTestSuite(Test1.class);
        s.addTestSuite(Test2.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Your third example does not work since the returned suite is empty, here one *must* return the suite subclass. As side note, the constructor in use exists only in Junit `3.8.2`

```
public class MyTestsuite extends TestSuite {
    MyTestsuite() {
        super(new Class[]{Test1.class, Test2.class});
    }
    public static Test suite() {
        return new MyTestsuite();
    }
}
```